# I want to generate random words as labels. i tried so many thing and it wouldn't work

Tags: python, random, kivy

by clicking correct button I want to generate random words from text document word list as labels. in `python` `kivy`. Here are my codes below:

```
import kivy
import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.uix.pagelayout import PageLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, StringProperty

class Begin1After(FloatLayout):
    count = 0
    my_text = StringProperty("0")

    def check_off(self):
        self.count += 1
        self.my_text = str(self.count)

    def incorrect_off(self):
        self.count -= 1
        self.my_text = str(self.count)

class MyApp(App):
    pass

myapp = MyApp()
myapp.run()
```

And here is my kivy code:

```
<Begin1After>:

    Label:
        text: root.my_text
        pos_hint: {'x': .03, 'y': .35}
        font_size: 20
        bold: True

    Label:
        text: "Team One:"
        bold: True
        pos_hint: {'x': -.05, 'y': .35}
        font_size: 20

    Button:
        size_hint: .06, .08
        pos_hint: {'x': .65, 'y': .1}
        background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
        on_release: root.check_off()

    Button:
        size_hint: .06, .08
        pos_hint: {'x': .3, 'y': .1}
        background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
        on_release: root.incorrect_off()
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem: focus.

What do you want ?

"I want to generate random words as labels. i tried so many thing and it wouldn't work"

Ok, that's the general idea but concretly, what is the next step you want to do ? What is the technical problematic that is blocking you right now ?

By looking at your code, I understand that you want to use a kivy App.

- create an App: done
- display the app ? Fail

So I can give you this answer:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
  
  
# Replace this with your 
# current version
kivy.require('1.11.1')  
  
# Defining a class
class MyFirstKivyApp(App):
      
    # Function that returns 
    # the root widget
    def build(self):
          
        # Label with text Hello World is 
        # returned as root widget
        return Label(text ="Hello World !")          
  
  
# Here our class is initialized
# and its run() method is called. 
# This initializes and starts 
# our Kivy application.
MyFirstKivyApp().run()
```

from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hello-world-in-kivy/
So now, based on this working code. What is the next step you want to do ?
Display 2 buttons and 2 labels ? go on and ask for help if you have a precise error to give.

Good luck ! :)